# How to get jquery ajax error data, and is it the correct way to respond?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, forms, django-forms

I'm using ajax to submit forms.
This is a piece of code I wrote:

```
    $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize())
        .done(function(data) {
            form.find(".success-msg").text(data);
        })
        .fail(function() {
            // insert error msg to the form
        })
        .always(function() {
             modal.modal("hide");
        });
```

How can I get the server response in the fail handler? the .fail() callback does not get the returned data like .done() do..

Second, is it correct to return non 200 (say 40X) status for a form validation errors that occur on the server? Or I should return 200 OK status and somehow distinguish myself between error/success in my own response?

i.e on validation errors I can do this

```
return HttpResponse(error_msg)
```

or,

```
return HttpResponseBadRequest(error_msg)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `done` part you have:

```
.done(function(data) {
    form.find(".success-msg").text(data);
});
```

But in the `fail` you didn't include the `data` argument. You should include it if you want to use it:

```
.fail(function(data) {
    // insert error msg to the form
});
```

Regarding the other question - if you know the reason for the fail - I think it's better to response with `200` and inside the response to have a `status: true/false` and the rest of the data. This way you can use different functions/behavior if you got some other error code (server not responding/server error/etc).

Answer (score 1):

This might be late but I had this same issue recently and this is my solution.

```
    .error(function(xhr){
       var result = xhr.responseJSON;
       form.find(".error-message").text(result.data);
     });
```

You can always console log xhr.responseJSON to be sure what's being returned.